# ipad safari browser crash

Tags: html, safari, mobile-safari

I have simple html page with slide.This page work on desktop browser very well but in ipad safari it crash,I only list 30 image in slide,what is problem with my code?How can I handle this?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Full Page</title>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="http://hybridsoftware.net/pf/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">  -->
  <style>
    .owl-nav>button {
      background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(240, 240, 240, 0.8) !important;
      border-radius: 0;
      display: block;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 10px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 46%;
      -webkit-transition: all .4s ease 0s;
      -moz-transition: all .4s ease 0s;
      -ms-transition: all .4s ease 0s;
      -o-transition: all .4s ease 0s;
      transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
      z-index: 6;
      width: 30px;
      height: 50px;
    }
    
    .owl-nav .owl-next {
      right: 0 !important;
    }
    
    .owl-nav>button>span {
      font-size: 30px;
    }
    
    @media (max-width: 768px) {
      .owl-nav>button {
        top: 36%;
      }
      .owl-nav .owl-next {
        top: 34% !important;
      }
    }
    
    @media (max-width: 768px) {
      .mobileh3 {
        font-size: 20px !important
      }
    }
    
    .mobileh3 {
      font-size: 35px
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <!-- partial:index.partial.html -->


  <div id="BroadCastDetail">
    <div id="example-carousel2" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">

      <div class="item"><img src="http://pfyonetim.demoticaret.com/patch/49086656-8f6e-45df-b2a9-4d2f309106f3_page1.jpg" alt=""></div>
      <div class="item"><img src="http://pfyonetim.demoticaret.com/patch/dfb8edd0-a82d-4c0c-afbb-4db06cdb6a13_page2.jpg" alt=""></div>
      <div class="item"><img src="http://pfyonetim.demoticaret.com/patch/54e69795-a825-4e7a-9fe2-0182bc318b63_page3.jpg" alt=""></div>
      <div class="item"><img src="http://pfyonetim.demoticaret.com/patch/d36a2885-80df-4d2e-b596-7dea0625ea5f_page4.jpg" alt=""></div>
      <div class="item"><img src="http://pfyonetim.demoticaret.com/patch/d17fe738-1fc5-41e3-a112-26e208ab21a4_page5.jpg" alt=""></div>
      <div class="item"><img src="http://pfyonetim.demoticaret.com/patch/e992e7f2-c8d3-475d-8f3c-d8c2ce0eab4d_page6.jpg" alt=""></div>
      <div class="item"><img src="http://pfyonetim.demoticaret.com/patch/ebf199a3-5500-4ede-990e-d144edfa774f_page7.jpg" alt=""></div>
      <div class="item"><img src="http://pfyonetim.demoticaret.com/patch/56f4d98d-085d-4e17-9805-63b99a733c1c_page8.jpg" alt=""></div>
      <div class="item"><img src="http://pfyonetim.demoticaret.com/patch/ab0b204f-1685-4db1-a370-79847f87cb8f_page9.jpg" alt=""></div>
      <div class="item"><img src="http://pfyonetim.demoticaret.com/patch/86fea027-73be-498e-992c-2ee49d37936c_page10.jpg" alt=""></div>
      <div class="item"><img src="http://pfyonetim.demoticaret.com/patch/15b350d1-d166-443c-a027-bc34e350c515_page11.jpg" alt=""></div>
      <div class="item"><img src="http://pfyonetim.demoticaret.com/patch/eb4e6632-9641-40bf-9f16-384f3898384f_page12.jpg" alt=""></div>
      <div class="item"><img src="http://pfyonetim.demoticaret.com/patch/6df8f9f2-ee8b-46bc-a894-a72256934d28_page13.jpg" alt=""></div>
      <div class="item"><img src="http://pfyonetim.demoticaret.com/patch/8e781c03-d8e2-4cd2-b848-e43770245ffa_page14.jpg" alt=""></div>
      <div class="item"><img src="http://pfyonetim.demoticaret.com/patch/77f9964a-3a5f-415b-a3f1-cf4ea2c96fae_page15.jpg" alt=""></div>
      <div class="item"><img src="http://pfyonetim.demoticaret.com/patch/062d38b5-9154-44a9-9ab2-5abacac98941_page16.jpg" alt=""></div>
      <div class="item"><img src="http://pfyonetim.demoticaret.com/patch/4817161b-b23a-4f2b-b0b6-6f75580263f2_page17.jpg" alt=""></div>
      <div class="item"><img src="http://pfyonetim.demoticaret.com/patch/b8f82f93-075d-4661-b457-f8ee195c62f4_page18.jpg" alt=""></div>
      <div class="item"><img src="http://pfyonetim.demoticaret.com/patch/9d96975e-52e9-45ac-b79a-9b7ed1204013_page19.jpg" alt=""></div>
      <div class="item"><img src="http://pfyonetim.demoticaret.com/patch/9f5f3b0a-4b5a-4050-8354-1a7dfd122897_page20.jpg" alt=""></div>
      <div class="item"><img src="http://pfyonetim.demoticaret.com/patch/445080ae-44f7-4eb4-97d0-3ed1872b6586_page21.jpg" alt=""></div>
      <div class="item"><img src="http://pfyonetim.demoticaret.com/patch/26f3be6e-c8be-44aa-8a62-ac51e2f7e562_page22.jpg" alt=""></div>
      <div class="item"><img src="http://pfyonetim.demoticaret.com/patch/2447f45f-c59b-41a9-b169-f5deed97375e_page23.jpg" alt=""></div>
      <div class="item"><img src="http://pfyonetim.demoticaret.com/patch/c9d755c1-edb5-4331-8bde-26f16d1c8d2f_page24.jpg" alt=""></div>
      <div class="item"><img src="http://pfyonetim.demoticaret.com/patch/72751d26-c466-4db4-ab9e-7ce907192001_page25.jpg" alt=""></div>
      <div class="item"><img src="http://pfyonetim.demoticaret.com/patch/181c7b7f-660b-4457-83d9-afb397180a52_page26.jpg" alt=""></div>
      <div class="item"><img src="http://pfyonetim.demoticaret.com/patch/951dee1f-7e9d-45ef-8256-2a4e3e8a27f7_page27.jpg" alt=""></div>
      <div class="item"><img src="http://pfyonetim.demoticaret.com/patch/d015b217-45c5-4a37-a584-29e1b3558d2a_page28.jpg" alt=""></div>
      <div class="item"><img src="http://pfyonetim.demoticaret.com/patch/5ef6deed-4900-4ae9-9ce9-6428e9a2a6ba_page29.jpg" alt=""></div>


    </div>
  </div>


  <script src="http://hybridsoftware.net/pf/assets/js/vendor.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://hybridsoftware.net/pf/js/loadingoverlay.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://hybridsoftware.net/pf/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

      var jsowl = document.createElement("script");
      jsowl.type = "text/javascript";
      jsowl.src = "http://hybridsoftware.net/pf/owl-carousel/owl.setting.js";
      setTimeout(function() {
        document.body.appendChild(jsowl);

      }, 3000);
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I created a snippet and added jQuery.

Comment: the images are 1MB each and 8000x45000pixels . Perhaps that is the reason?

Comment: Yes @mplungjan but is that problem?In that page there are 30 images and each images is 1-2 mb with 8k-45k pixels,is that problem?How can I handle this?I can optimize images but quality is problem.Is that issue is about my code or ipad issues?If Ipad issues any solution?

Comment: Seems it is. The images are silly large